# How to skip not available product in loop_shop_per_page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change  the number of products in category page

```
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function ( $cols ) {
        return 40;
    }, 20 );
```

But I get less products.
Because I hidden the products that are not in stock.
How can I to get only stock product in loop_shop_per_page?